# JSDom's querySelectorAll function not retrieving elements inside of <div>

Tags: jestjs, jsdom

jsdom version 15.1.1 jest version 24.9.0 node.js version 10.16.0

I am trying to get information from an offline html page by using

```
var summaryInfo = document.querySelectorAll(".className");
Array.prototype.slice.call(summaryInfo).forEach(n => ... }
```

In this case there should return 6 arrays of info, but I only get 2

The same exact code works fine in a normal browser, but when I use jsdom with jest it has this problem

I put in a log to see what was being passed through and found with the 2 that work the outermost tag is an `<li>` and everything inside is just as it should be, but with the other elements the outermost tag is a `<div>` interestingly nothing shows up inside.

I also checked the html document I am drawing from to make sure that those `<div>` elements are indeed not empty and they aren't.

Any help that you can provide would be much appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the HTML page had a structure where some `<li>` tags did not have surrounding `<ul>` containers. While this worked in browsers like Chrome and Firefox, that was more because the browsers were designed to correct problems like that. Intrinsically my problem is with the HTML page I am trying to use and I can't correct that.